# mongo DB change strem with load balancing in production env

Tags: node.js, mongodb, stream, changestream

**mongo change stream with load balancing**

Can any one  help  as how  we can achieve mango change stream with load balanceing server..?
we are working on micro service architecture facing issue  on production   when i go with load balanceing the same code is deployed over the 4 server  when i perform any operation on single server the change stream trigger is fired form all the 4  server.
So what i want  it should be trigger from same server where the   operation are performed

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us some code perhaps?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use MongoDB change streams with node js via a REST API microservice (built with Express)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61344049/how-to-use-mongodb-change-streams-with-node-js-via-a-rest-api-microservice-buil)

Comment: Sure @AvivLo  i think code is working fine as it has to  work   
**you can check if i am  wrong please correct me**

async userWatch(db) {
        try {
            let userCollection = db.collection('users');
            let userChangeStream = userCollection.watch({ fullDocument: "updateLookup" });
            userChangeStream.on('change', async (change) =>{
            })
        } 
    }

Answer (score 0):

Change stream is a database-level concept. Data is inserted/updated/deleted from the database, this produces change events. Any number of subscribers can subscribe to the change events and do whatever they want to do with the changes. *Each subscriber* is notified of every change event.

A change stream is not meant to inform the application that *originated* the change of the said change. This is redundant - the application already knows what it did.

Consider rephrasing your question to explain what you are trying to accomplish better.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "manage change stream with load balanceing server".

Comment: I have 4 connections from 4 different servers(under load balancer) and whenever there is a change in any of the collections there are 4 request generated. So i want to stop this behaviour and only one server should create that change stream request

Is there any another  way to manage this issue   because we can not go with single  subscribers  if one server goes down  change stream will stop i.e data sync will get stop   between servers right...?

Comment: You are describing a work queue of which there are many implementations. A change stream is a broadcast mechanism and does not sound  appropriate for your task.

Comment: Actually I still do not understand if you are asking about the producing side or the consuming side.

Comment: I am asking about consumer side

Comment: For the consumer side, use a work queue with multiple workers.